# Replace specific values in one row

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to replace two values, `Value` and `Value1`, in a row with the specific name (`Description`).

```
df <- data.frame(  
  Description = c("15A","11","12"),
  Value = c(200,196,NA),
  Value1 = c(300,196,NA),
  ValueTested = c(20,10,NA),
  ApplyValues = c(60,10,NA)
)

df
```

Now I expect from the code, first to find the row in column Description with value `15A` and to change the corresponding row in the column `Value` ( from 200 to 100 ) and `Value1` (from 300 to 150). I tried with the code below, but this code is related to the position of value `15A`. So if this value goes, let's say, down this line will not work.

```
df$Value[1] = 100
df$Value1[1]= 100
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and get the result as a result below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can use `rows_update()` to modify rows of a table according to another table of data by matching a set of key variables.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rows_update(tibble(Description = '15A', Value = 100, Value1 = 150),
              by = "Description")

#   Description  Value  Value1  ValueTested ApplyValues
# 1         15A    100*    150*          20          60
# 2          11    196     196           10          10
# 3          12     NA      NA           NA          NA
```